# didnt work DialogFragment with 1 button.

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-fragments

Why doesn't my code work?

I need dialogFragment with 1 button.

---

I have 2 classes:

```
   public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

 static DialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment f = new MyAlertDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }


 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, container, false);
     Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

     return v;
 }

}
```

---

and Activity:

```
   public class DialogFragmentActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
showDialog();
}

void showDialog() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(1);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}

    }
```

How do you complete this fragment?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Don't override onCreateView, override onCreateDialog:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
    return alert.create();
}
```